# show an element that's not a child of the anchor with pure css

Tags: html, css

I want to trigger the element to display the hidden elements on hover

HTML

```
<div class="contents">
   <aside>
     <section class="tumb">
       <a class="placeHoldTumb" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
       <a class="placeHoldTumb" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
     </section>
   </aside>
   <div class="hidden">
      <a href="#" class="one" ><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000/bada55" width="500px" ></a>
      <a href="#" class="two" ><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000/bada55" width="500px" ></a>
   </div>
   <a href="#" class="background" ><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000/000000/bada55" width="500px" /></a>
</div><!-- end contents -->
```

CSS

```
aside  {
  z-index: 100;
  background: rgba(0, 182, 173, 0.9); 
  width: 230px; 
  position: absolute; }
aside .tumb img { 
  margin: 5px; position: relative; }
.contents img {
  position: absolute; }
.hidden img {  opacity: 0; }

.tumb a:hover ~ .hidden img {
  opacity: 1;
  filter:alpha(opacity=100); /*For IE8*/ }
```

demo here: http://codepen.io/mvaneijgen/pen/ELBAg

Comment: You can't. You'll need to use jQuery or vanilla JS for that.

Comment: Which element should reveal which elements, and what have you already tried (and / or what's the problem with what you've tried)? More info will get you more answers.

Comment: just a question. Why dont you want to use 
                  .hidden a:hover img {opacity:1...}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 0):

try the below CSS in your code... it will work

```
.hidden{ 
opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0); 
}
.contents:hover .hidden{
opacity: 1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

I have tried your code in Fiddle... refer this link : http://jsfiddle.net/NUBkp/14/